# Error: Could not find or load main class src.klase.Main Eclipse SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I downloaded a project from SVN onto my laptop and, when I try to run it, it says

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class src.klase.Main .
```

I tried Project>Cleanup, restarting, everything I could think of.
My .classpath file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre1.8.0_65"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

There are no problem with the classes, I created a new project, added them in it and it run successfully.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: No, I'm compiling it in Eclipse. Run Configurations are in order-project name and main class name...